# How to set default values for .mode and .headers to control output format in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Normally I use these settings to have `SQLite` output pretty structure:

```
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .headers on
```

But how to make them default settings?

Answer (score 9):

From the *man* page.

> If the file `~/.sqliterc` exists, it is processed first.  can be found in the user's home directory, it is read and processed.  It should generally only contain meta-commands.

So put them into `~/.sqliterc`.