# Select from sqlite without headers

Tags: python, select, sqlite

I was wondering if there is a way to programatically select from an sqlite3 table and get a result set *without* headers. I have found several related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924149/how-to-configure-sqlite-to-display-headers-by-default) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911865/set-default-output-format-for-sqlite) which solve the problem by calling `.headers OFF`, but this option seems to only apply to the command line sqlite client. For reference, here is my python query code (less some exception handling):

```
con = lite.connect('my_db.sqlite')
sql = 'SELECT * FROM some_table'
cur = execute(sql, con)
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

The value of `rows` then becomes

```
[
    (100, 102460, 18994), 
    (200, 102460, 13056), 
    (300, 102460, 10784), 
    (400, 102460, 9153), 
    (u'sample_size', u'total_tok', u'unknown_tok_mean')
]
```

Note how the last item is the header returned by sqlite. This will only be present from time to time (tends to be there when there are many rows returned). I need a way to control whether the header is returned- either way is fine, as long as the results are  *consistent*.

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: There you go, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that last row is data returned from the table. A select would *never* include the column headers in the row data.

That info *is* available, but as a `.description` attribute on the cursor, never in the result of `.fetchall()`.

In other words, something else inserted that data into your table, and the `SELECT` is merely returning that information.

What the command line client does is format results for you, and it'll add the header info if so configured, but that is not behaviour that is part of the `SELECT` statement in and of itself.